# PostgreSQL Grant user access to execute functions without table permissions and with RLS

Tags: database, postgresql

In a multi tenant database table structure, a user can only see the data that he has access to, which is achieved by RLS. Additionally, the user can only execute functions and are not given permissions to tables used inside the function. I'm aware that we can use security definer in the function to execute on the owner perspective but the owner has access to all tenants data and then the user who executes it is able to see all. How can I give permission to user who can only execute function and can only see his own data without giving him SELECT permission on tables?

Answer (score 0):

Use [SECURITY DEFINER](https://%20https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) on the create function. Be sure to notice the security warning `Writing SECURITY DEFINER Functions Safely` section.

Comment: I already wrote in my question that I'm using security definer. Please read question properly.